# how to reset stream open flags?

Tags: c++, stream

So what I'm doing is creating a stringstream in binary mode. Somewhere along the line I don't want to treat it as binary anymore but as a regular string stream.

Looking through the documentation the only time streams care about whether they are binary, input or output (ios_base::openmode flags) is at construction. You can change the manipulator flags and the error flags, but apparently not the openmode flags? Maybe I'm not looking hard enough?

So what I'm currently doing is something like

```
std::stringstream memory( ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::binary );
boost::iostreams::copy( *source_file, memory );
```

And somewhere along the line I would like to be able to do something like

```
memory.reset_openmode( ios_base::in | ios_base::out );
```

Comment: Do you reaaaally need newline translation? Especially in in-memory streams?

Comment: Is that *all* the binary flag does? So you're saying if I open something in binary mode that later when I want to treat it as text I can do all the `memory >> somestring` I want with only the new line character not being read in properly

Answer (score 0):

What you could do (and also what I would do) is that I would close the stream, then reopen the stream as a basic text file, setting the seekg(), and the seekp() flags as necessary.

Comment: Its a string stream, not an fstream so there's no closing it. I'm using boosts copy to get data from a custom file_source class that handles a zip archive. I could delay the copy to when I know whether I want the stream to be binary or character, but maybe later I won't have that luxury and I just want to know how to handle that.

Comment: Whats the difference between a string stream, and an fsteream, I've never herd of it. I know that they both can use raw binary, and I know that fstream can be changed to a string input stream, and then back again when you need it.

Comment: well, for one, if I close an fstream, it writes it everything in it to disk. I do not want anything being written to disk. As that would mean my application is extracting zipped files to disk, and then using the extracted files to read them! Not a great way to do things.